# Method Error 500 for CascadingDropDownExtender in AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax

I am working on CascadingDropDownExtender in AJAX. When I run the sample, I am getting “[Method Error 500]” in the Dropdowns. I wrote a Web Service (carService.asmx) to get the values from the XML (carService.xml) into the Dropdowns. Even the Web Service is not invoking correctly. When I run the Web Service, an XML is generated with errors. Please help me with the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging your webservice. Looks like thats where the problem is. Have a look at this Microsoft article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311766

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for a answer, but it could help somebody else.

I had a similar issue, but initially I was getting a "method error 415", then later a "method error 500". I would suggest checking your bindings for the webservice.

What I realized is that I accidental added the service as a Silverlight enabled service instead of a AJAX enabled service. I ended up redoing the service bindings in the web.config, which lead to the "method error 500". Obviously I modified the service bindings incorrectly and instead ended up recreating the service but as a AJAX enable service. Everything worked as expected afterwards.

P.S.
I am using WCF services, but I am sure the same applies for normal webservices.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry for late answer  i think this will help in future who w'll get this error in ajax cascadedropdown for error 500 is solved for me this error because of changing parameter values for the binding method as clearly showed below

** Initially **

public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] BindCountrydropdown(string value, string text)
    {
        SqlConnection concountry = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
        concountry.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdcountry = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Countries", concountry);
        SqlDataAdapter dacountry = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdcountry);
        cmdcountry.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet dscountry = new DataSet();
        dacountry.Fill(dscountry);
        concountry.Close();
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> countrydetails = new      List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach(DataRow dtrow in dscountry.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string CountryID = dtrow["IDCountry"].ToString();
            string CountryName = dtrow["CountryName"].ToString();
            countrydetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(CountryName,CountryID));
        }
        return countrydetails.ToArray();
    }


i got error 500 i found solution because of changing parmeter name in above method solution is given below u must pass parmaters as(knownCategoryValues,category) don't change parameter name

** Solution **
  public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] BindCountrydropdown(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        SqlConnection concountry = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
        concountry.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdcountry = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Countries", concountry);
        SqlDataAdapter dacountry = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdcountry);
        cmdcountry.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet dscountry = new DataSet();
        dacountry.Fill(dscountry);
        concountry.Close();
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> countrydetails = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach(DataRow dtrow in dscountry.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string CountryID = dtrow["IDCountry"].ToString();
            string CountryName = dtrow["CountryName"].ToString();
            countrydetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(CountryName,CountryID));
        }
        return countrydetails.ToArray();
    }

i think this will help for u
```